# Relational Database Design For Follow/Friend Relationship

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I am trying to make a social media app by postgresql and php and I am having problem to simplize friendship and follow relation between users I am planing to make two tables users and relationship/follow

```
USERS table 
--id----username----
   1    user1
   2    user2
   3    user3
   4    user4

RELATION TABLE
---user_id---follow_user_id---
     1           2
     2           1
     1           3
     3           2
```

and I want to be able to differentiate whether user is my friend or just I am following him
as a list following users and my friends in a single query if its possible.

I thought of making another column in the relationship table as type and put friend or follow when user makes a request but this will cause to make a lot of query to check if other person is following me or not if he is set as friend if not set as follow and when he follows make the same check etc. So I am wondering if there is a better structure to make this friendship model with relational databases

Comment: It is a directed graph. The relation_table contains the *arrows*. If you want the arrows in the opposite direction you only need to swap the two fields when refering to them.

Comment: @wildplasser can you provide an example ? I did not get what you meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE users
        ( id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , username text not NULL UNIQUE
        );

INSERT INTO users (id, username) VALUES
   (1 ,'me' )
   , (2 ,'user2' )
   , (3 ,'user3' )
   , (4 ,'user4' )
        ;

CREATE TABLE relations
        ( id integer not NULL REFERENCES users(id)
        , follows integer not NULL REFERENCES users(id)
        ,  PRIMARY KEY (id, follows)
        ,  UNIQUE (follows,id)
        );

INSERT INTO relations (id, follows) VALUES
     (1,2 )
     , (2,1 )
     , (1,3 )
     , (3,2  )
        ;

-- who follows me ?
SELECT * FROM users u
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM relations r WHERE r.follows = u.id AND r.id = 1);

-- who do I follow ?
SELECT * FROM users u
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM relations r WHERE r.id = u.id AND r.follows = 1);
```

---

Result:

---

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 4
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 4
 id | username 
----+----------
  2 | user2
  3 | user3
(2 rows)

 id | username 
----+----------
  2 | user2
(1 row)
```

---

And if you want the followers that you follow back:

---

```
-- who do I follow who also follows me back ?
SELECT * FROM users u
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM relations r WHERE r.id = u.id AND r.follows = 1)
  AND EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM relations r WHERE r.follows = u.id AND r.id = 1)
        ;
```

---

Find **all** pairs of mutual friends:

---

```
-- Find all pairs of mutual friends
SELECT u1.username AS username1
        , u2.username AS username2
FROM users u1
JOIN users u2 ON EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM relations r WHERE r.id = u1.id AND r.follows = u2.id)
                AND EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM relations r WHERE r.follows = u1.id AND r.id = u2.id)
WHERE u1.id < u2 .id -- tie/symmetry-breaker
        ;
```

---

Result:

---

```
 username1 | username2 
-----------+-----------
 me        | user2
(1 row)
```

---

`EXISTS` yields a boolean, which you can use in the result:

---

```
-- Find all pairs of any kind of friends
SELECT u1.username AS username1
        , u2.username AS username2
        , EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM relations r WHERE r.id = u1.id AND r.follows = u2.id) AS ab
        , EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM relations r WHERE r.follows = u1.id AND r.id = u2.id) AS ba
FROM users u1
JOIN users u2 ON EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM relations r WHERE r.id = u1.id AND r.follows = u2.id)
                OR EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM relations r WHERE r.follows = u1.id AND r.id = u2.id)
WHERE u1.id < u2 .id -- tie/symmetry-breaker
        ;
```

---

Result:

---

```
 username1 | username2 | ab | ba 
-----------+-----------+----+----
 me        | user2     | t  | t
 me        | user3     | t  | f
 user2     | user3     | f  | t
(3 rows)
```

Comment: thanks for your effort but this example showing how to get my followers and my follows but I need a list that shows whether the people I follow are my friends (  they follow me too ) or not

Comment: Just combine the queries (are you new to SQL?)

Comment: thats usefull but I think we misunderstand each other a need a list that giving me whether a users in that list is my friend or not ex:  - user1 friend , - user2 following , -user3 friend , -user4 following etc. both my friends and the people i follow as a list basicly

Comment: but i think it can be achieved by an or statement

Comment: but still i need a column telling me whether its a friend or just someone the user follows

Answer (score 0):

To normalize this, you should have a type column, with a foreign key to a relationshiptype table. Then you'll have one record per relationship.

However, if you know that you'll only have friends and follower types, it sounds more pragmatic to just add two Y/N columns to the relation table.

And if they're mutually exclusive, maybe a single column (besides the two user columns) is enough, to denote the relation type. But I don't know how you want to model your domain, so that's up to you :)

Comment: why I should add two column if I add just one column i can differentiate if someone is friend or just a following but this is causing me to make other queries to keep that column up to date

Comment: It depends, if somebody can be both a friend and a follower, then you'll need to store both somewhere. If somebody is either a friend OR a follower, then no, you don't need a second field.

Comment: yeah If users follow each other I consider them friends

Answer (score 0):

Another option to list just the friend definition where A follows B and B follows A. Build a CTE in which the relation hold true, then join the users table (twice) to get user's name.

```
with friends(lid, fid) as
     (select r1.id, r1.follows 
        from relations r1
       where exists ( select null 
                        from relations r2 
                       where (r1.id,r1.follows) =
                             (r2.follows,r2.id)
                    )
      )
select u1.username, u2.username
  from friends f
  join users u1 on u1.id=f.lid
  join users u2 on u2.id=f.fid;
```

The following returns the bi-directional relation ships A,B and B,A. To derive just a single 'copy' of the friends relationship just add a where predicate.

```
with friends(lid, fid) as
     (select r1.id, r1.follows 
        from relations r1
       where exists ( select null 
                        from relations r2 
                       where (r1.id,r1.follows) =
                             (r2.follows,r2.id)
                    )
      )
select u1.username, u2.username
  from friends f
  join users u1 on u1.id=f.lid
  join users u2 on u2.id=f.fid
 where u1.id < u2.id;
```

There is no need for another column to define the relationship - which can become a maintenance nightmare. Consider how such a column would need changing in the following:

- Users A and B exist, but no relation between them.
- User B starts following User A.
- User A later starts following user B
- User B later stops following User A.